# Selecting a front derailleur: parameters

Tags: derailleur

The spec sheet for the Shimano Alivio FD-M430 front derailleur contains a number of points that I don't understand.

- What does "Maximum capacity: 22 teeth" mean?
- Why are "Top gear teeth" constrained to "44/48T"? Is there anything wrong with 46?
- What is "Cable Routing: dual-pull type"?
- And most puzzling, what is "Chain Stay Angle  63-66 / 66-69" and how do I measure mine?

Comment: Max capacity is the max difference between rings.  44/48 would imply anything in that range is OK.  Pull type is up pull or down pull.  Dunno about stay angle.

Comment: @ Daniel R Hicks, great. Please clarify about pull. There is a separate characteristic, that says it's top-swing(i.e. the cable comes down the seattube, and not under the downtube).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Derailleurs, fortunately have been fairly standardized. Simple specs like these can help you determine what derailleur is best for your bike. Here's a brief overview of some of these:

- **Maximum capacity**: The maximum number of teeth between the largest and smallest rings. eg. 48T-22T = 26T.
- **Top gear teeth**: The range available for the largest ring. Any size ring in this range will work. Even some rings outside this range may work, but not to their best potential.
- **Cable routing**: Derailleurs come in multiple pull types:

  - *Top Swing*: The clamp is below the cage and the cage pivots above the clamp. The cable attaches from above.
  - *Bottom Swing*: The cage is below the clamp and swings from below the clamp. The cable attaches from below.
  - *Dual Pull*: Can pull from either direction.
- **Chain Stay Angle**: The chainstay angle is the angle between the chain stay and the seat tube. The derailleur must fit this angle or risk the cage hitting the chain stay.

Of course, [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html) has some good information, but if you really want to dive into all those numbers, have a chat with a mechanic at your LBS. I didn't know anything about these angles until my mechanic pointed out that my seat tube angle changed near the BB and meant I should have a bottom swing instead of the top swing I bought. It works, but doesn't provide the best shifting possible.

Comment: Does the `Maximum capacity` number indicates the smallest chainring or the difference from the largest to the smallest?

Comment: @Vorac The difference between the two.

Comment: Also, the device is listed as both `TOP-SWING` and `dual-pull type`. The top-swing part is not important?

Comment: That means it swings from the top, but the cable can be routed from either above or below.